# Problems with PropertyValue when Graph's vertices are Lists

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I create a [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graph.html) which vertices are lists (points in n-dimensional space)

```
v1 = {{1, 2} -> {3, 4}, {5, 6} -> {7, 8}};
g1 = Graph[v1];
PropertyValue[{g1, VertexList[g1][[1]]}, VertexWeight] = 10
```

and I get a message error:

> ```
> Set::write: Tag PropertyValue in PropertyValue[...] is protected
> ```

Now, if I do

```
v2 = {1 -> 2, 3 -> 4};
g2 = Graph[v2];
PropertyValue[{g2, VertexList[g2][[1]]}, VertexWeight] = 10
```

everything is fine.

`g1` and `g2` are structurally indentical, the difference is only in vertices type: list(`g1`) and scalar(`g2`).

What's the problem here?

Comment: I think it is better not to use lists as vertices as it can introduce all sorts of similar interferences. I would advice you to use another wrapper instead of `List`, e.g. `Graph[{f[1,2]->f[3,4], ...}]`.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you specify weights in the following way:

```
g = Graph[{{1, 2} -> {3, 4}, {5, 6} -> {7, 8}}];
g = SetProperty[g, VertexWeight -> {{1, 2} -> 10}];
PropertyValue[g, VertexWeight]
```

> ```
> {10, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

Comment: Ok, so SetProperty works here. Thanks.