# Setting PropertyValue for VertexWeight is not persistent

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.0**

---

```
g = CompleteGraph[8, VertexSize -> Medium];


PropertyValue[{g, VertexList[g][[1]]}, VertexWeight] = 10;    
PropertyValue[g, VertexWeight]
```

> ```
> {10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

```
PropertyValue[{g, VertexList[g][[2]]}, VertexWeight] = 10;    
PropertyValue[g, VertexWeight]
```

> ```
> {1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

```
PropertyValue[{g, VertexList[g][[3]]}, VertexWeight] = 10;
PropertyValue[g, VertexWeight]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

How come that I see only the last result from `PropertyValue`? It applies only to `VertexWeight` property. When I set `VertexStyle` (like in docs), everything is fine: I can change the vertex color one by one.

Comment: Beats me. A bug?

Comment: Interestingly, the very same examples work with `VertexLabels` instead of `VertexWeight`, so I guess `VertexWeights` always resets the weights for all vertices to 1 (the default value) when setting with `PropertyValue[...] = val`. Definitely unwanted behaviour, but sadly it is just one in a long list of annoyances with `Graph`... You should report it to Tech Support.

Comment: Furthermore, not even `SetProperty` works here (as it worked [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32305/problems-with-propertyvalue-when-graphs-vertices-are-lists)), in any form.

Comment: I also note that the example in `SetProperty`'s doc page (Scope/Basic Properties) `PropertyValue[{%, 1}, VertexWeight]` shows a result of `$Failed`, indicating a problem at the time of generating the docs (though it now executes as intended).

Comment: Ok, I report this to the Support. Until then, all graph techniques that are dependent on weights are useless, I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from the Tech Support:

> I have reproduced this problem and agree that the behavior with VertexWeight is not desirable.  I have filed a report with our developers on the problem so that it can be fixed in a future version of Mathematica.

Ticket number is 265525 (just in case)