# GraphDistance error when Graph vertices are Associations

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.0**

 Note: Associations are new in 10.0

---

Here is a nice graph whose vertices are `Associations`:

```
g = Graph[{
   <|"n" -> 1|> -> <|"n" -> 2|>,
   <|"n" -> 1|> -> <|"n" -> 3|>,
   <|"n" -> 2|> -> <|"n" -> 4|>,
   <|"n" -> 3|> -> <|"n" -> 4|>},
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image: graph with associations as vertices]

Several graph functions work as expected, e.g., `AcyclicGraphQ[g]` and `AdjacencyMatrix[g]`.

However, functions that refer explicitly to the vertices don't work:

```
GraphDistance[g, <|"n" -> 2|>, <|"n" -> 4|>]
```

**"GraphDistance: Unknown option "n" in GraphDistance."**

Or:

```
GraphDistance[g, <|"n" -> 2|>]
```

**"GraphDistance: GraphDistance called with 1 argument; 2 or 3 arguments are expected."**

It looks like it's interpreting the `Association` as a bunch of options to `GraphDistance`. Is that use of `Associations` documented somewhere?

(It seems that using non-integer vertices causes problems: [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32305/problems-with-propertyvalue-when-graphs-vertices-are-lists).)

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty confident that this will be fixed in the next version. :-) But do report it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, this another one in a long row of issues with noninteger vertices for `Graph` where things neither work as documented nor as they should. Since `GraphDistance` is a kernel function, we non-insiders cannot tell why this happens. (But every now and then, associations are interpreted as list of rules; e.g. when used as second argument of `ReplaceAll`.)

What I can do for you is to provide a way to circumvent that by using integer vertices and the associations as vertex labels. For looking up a vertex from its label, we employ an association `a`.

```
edgelist = {<|"n" -> 1|> -> <|"n" -> 2|>, <|"n" -> 1|> -> <|"n" -> 3|>, <|"n" -> 2|> -> <|"n" -> 4|>, <|"n" -> 3|> -> <|"n" -> 4|>};   
vertexlist = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[List @@@ edgelist]]];
a = AssociationThread[vertexlist, Range[Length[vertexlist]]];
```

Visuably, we obtain the same graph:

```
g = Graph[
  Map[a, edgelist, {2}],
  VertexLabels -> KeyValueMap[{key, val} \[Function] val -> key, a]
  ]
```

[image]

In calls to `Graph`-related function that require vertices as argument, we have to insert the lookup function `a`:

```
GraphDistance[g, a[<|"n" -> 2|>], a[<|"n" -> 4|>]]
```

> 1

Comment: Thank you! And regarding the behavior where an Association as a final argument is interpreted as options, is this known behavior?

Comment: No, I don't think so. For example, `Graphics[Disk[], <|PlotRange -> {-10, 10}|>]` produces errors while `Graphics[Disk[], Normal@<|PlotRange -> {-10, 10}|>]` works as expected. But option processing is not handled consistently, even among built-in functions. An in particular `Graph`-related functions process their arguments in a very obfuscated and inconsistent way (e.g. flattening out lists so that using lists as vertices causes errors in a similar way).

Comment: [I once browsed `HighlightGraph` and its backend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161433/38178) to repair a bug for Szabolcs. (Fortunately, the bug was _not completely_ hidden in the kernel) and it got me the creeps how WRI processes the input. There were at least a dozen of layers of abstraction to unravel before I could find the actual bug (which was in itself not that complicated). But I have to admit that writing computational code is one thing and that writing code for user interaction is an entirely different thing.

Answer (score 4):

This is clearly a bug, and as Henrik said, a fairly common type of bug, unfortunately. When you encounter such problems, please do report them to Wolfram.

As a workaround, you can use `IGDistanceMatrix` from my [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

```
<<IGraphM`

IGDistanceMatrix[g, {<|"n" -> 2|>}, {<|"n" -> 4|>}]
(* {{1}} *)
```

This function takes only *lists* of vertices as the 2nd and 3rd argument. It does not take single vertex names. This is a mild inconvenience, but on the upside, it eliminates any ambiguities whether an expression is a vertex list or a single vertex name that happens to be a list (or association or whatever).

Comment: I have reported the bug! Thank you for the information about IGraph/M.